# Conditional Yup Validation for Dynamic Dropdowns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, formik, yup

I have a dropdown list of countries, and based on the selected country, the dropdown for states is populated. Some countries don't have states, so validation is not needed in those cases. I've attempted to implement this using Yup for validation. Can you review my code and let me know if it's correct and if there is another way to implement this?

```
import * as Yup from "yup";

const noSpecialCharactersRegExp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,10}$/;

export const Shchema = Yup.object({
  country: Yup.string().required('Country is required').max(120),
  state: Yup.string()
    .when('state', {
      is: options => options.length > 1,
      then: Yup.string()
        .required("State is required")
        .matches(noSpecialCharactersRegExp, "State is not valid")
        .max(100),
      otherwise: Yup.string().notRequired()
    }),
});
```

If the state options.length is greater than 1, then the field is required, otherwise it is not required.

I tried creating an array of countries that do not have states and if that country is selected, then no validation will occur.